# Woocommerce delete download permission to refunded orders, using a query trigger in wc core function

Tags: php, mysql, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have searched and finally found a way to run a mysql query:

`DELETE
FROM wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions.order_id 
    AND wp_posts.post_status = 'wc-refunded');`

to delete download permission FROM all refunded orders (`wc-refunded`).

i am trying to trigger this automatic in  `wc-order-functions.php` https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-order-functions.php

this function add entries permission to `wc-completed` and `wc-processing` orders (found this at line `#427`, `#428`), and delete permission to wc-cancelled (i dont found this in this function) by default core, how i can apply my mysql query to this scenario and automatic remove download permission to all order has become `wc-cancelled` our a better way to do this hooked our automatic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching some posts i have modded the query to run in a function, its working and prevent download permission after digital product order become refunded:

```
function mysite_refunded($order_id) {
$sql = "DELETE
FROM wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM wp_posts
WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions.order_id AND wp_posts.post_status = 'wc-refunded');";
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->get_results($sql);
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_refunded', 'mysite_refunded', 10, 1);
```